# How to view from the Lamp’s perspective?

Tags: 3d-view

I would like to be able to view the scene from each light’s POV. Is this possible in a simple way, without having to parent a camera to each light and look through each camera?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Non-Camera objects including lamps can be used as cameras objects in Blender.

Select the light you want and make it the active camera (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>), then manipulate it as you would a camera for positioning / rotation / etc...

You may also want to enable *Lock Camera to View*, so you can use regular view manipulation to place the camera.